# Observation of cosmological topological defects

Tags: cosmology, experimental-physics

Are there any projects/experiments running for the observation of topological defects (domain walls, monopoles, etc)?

Are there any *past/canceled* or *future* such projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See e.g.

> http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ex/0302011

MoEDAL at CERN has survived since that time. This is about the magnetic monopoles. Domain walls may be too much stuff too wish for so I don't think that someone is looking for them and nothing else. Cosmic strings are being constantly looked for in the telescopes but so far, the bounds are tightening - they don't seem to be abundant (or they're totally absent).

Answer (score 1):

There is a [workshop](http://axion-wimp.desy.de/) on Axions, WIMPs and WISPs which will be held at Mykonos, Royal Myconian & Myconian Imperial Resorts on 26 June - 1 July 2011.